# github very irritating condition or not finding local repo directory and not able to edit files

Tags: git, node.js

after an hour of messing around with git (new to its use) im just not able to find the git repo directory to edit the package.json file because im trying to install this

```
https://github.com/davidcoallier/node-php/blob/master/README.md
```

and as soon i run the

```
npm install
```

i get this error

```
npm WARN package.json nodephp@0.1.1 Invalid dependency: fastcgi 1
```

now i understand i need to update the repo within that json file but windows fails to find it. could someone assist me in finding this or a work around for this.

can anyone please guide me on how to install this repo

```
https://github.com/billywhizz/node-fastcgi-parser
```

Thanks guys.

Answer (score 0):

Read the error message a little more carefully. You're missing fastcgi, a dependency. You need to install fastcgi first, so that dependencies are satisfied. The install instructions on the page you linked tell you to install fastcgi.

https://github.com/billywhizz/node-fastcgi-parser

Comment: from this page https://github.com/davidcoallier/node-php it tells me to install this one https://github.com/billywhizz/node-fastcgi-parser   can u please guide me... im new to git

Comment: but how do i install it bro. seem to gave no installation instructions for it https://github.com/billywhizz/node-fastcgi-parser

Comment: im new to git and i tried npm install fastcgi-parser on node and i got a module but im not sure how to proceed now.